# Qt4, как выполнить функцию по получению сигнала и направить результат в слот?

Tags: qt, c++

Имеются doubleSpinBox, label и функция double conv(double).
Вот это работает:

> connect(doubleSpinBox,
> SIGNAL(valueChanged(double)), label,
> SLOT(setNum(double)));

Нужно, что бы в label вставлялся результат conv() от текущего значения doubleSpinBox.
Как это правильно осуществить?

Comment: Собственно, правильное решение оказалось такое:
1) объявить свой слот
public slots:
 void label_valueChanged(double value);
2) создать его
void MainWindow::label_valueChanged(double value)
{
 double result = conv(value);
 label->setNum(result);
}
3) подключить слот к сигналу
connect(doubleSpinBox, SIGNAL(valueChanged(double)), this, SLOT(label_valueChanged(double)));

Answer (score 1):

В методе `setNum` устанавливать значение label'а не пробовали?